# Heroku - Fatal error doing git push heroku master

Tags: git, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm learning Ruby On Rails and are trying to do the 
[Ruby On Rails Tutorial](http://www.railstutorial.org/book/) by Michael Hartl.

I'm doing the tutorial on a MacBookPro running OSX 10.6.8

My problem is this.
After creating the repo locally, and after creating the app at Heroku the push to Heroku fails after 'Initializing Repository'

```
"Fredrik-Nilssons-MacBook-Pro:demo_app fredriknilsson$ git push heroku master
Initializing repositoryReceived disconnect from 50.19.85.154: 10: user closed connection
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists."
```

I've scanned the web and tried to follow the tips explained especially here on stackoverflow.
The thing is that all examples I've seen aren't exactly the same but are in the surrounding ball park so to say.

I've created and published the public key at both github and heroku.

Comment: Did you run `heroku create`?

Comment: Is this resolved? I have the exact same problem deploying an angular fullstack application.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem.

My ASDL modem dropped packages. Verify that you don't have connection problems.
The problems I had only surfaced when using GIT+SSH against Heroku. I haven't dug deeper into the connection problem besides that I saw a RST followed by loads of retransmits in Wireshark. After some time the connection was closed.

See this link:
[Answer to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25217746/git-push-heroku-master-user-closed-connection/25226753#25226753)