# git push heroku master - user closed connection

Tags: node.js, git, heroku

I am having some really strange problems deploying the official **heroku** sample node application to **Heroku**.

I am following every step in the article *"Getting Started with `Node.js` on Heroku"* https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs but keep getting the error message:

```
git push heroku master
Initializing repositoryReceived disconnect from 50.19.85.156: 10: user closed connection
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Anyone who have had similar problems?

My own application is derived from angular-fullstack but even this getting started guide fails for me.

**I have tried (with no success):**

> - Replacing my old rsa keys with new one.
> - Creating an alternate Heroku account.
> - Archlinux and osx
> - OSX reinstalling node, brew and gems.

**Other information:**

> - OSX (10.9)
>
>   - heroku-toolbelt/3.9.6 (x86_64-darwin10.8.0) ruby/1.9.3\
>   - git version 1.8.5.2 (Apple Git-48)
>   - npm 2.0.0-alpha-5
>   - node v0.10.30
> - Linux
>
>   - heroku-toolbelt/3.9.6 (x86_64-linux) ruby/2.1.2
>   - git version 2.0.4
>   - npm 1.4.21
>   - node v0.10.30

Anyone who have had similar problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved.

It seems my Thomson Gateway modem with firewall functionality interfered with GIT protocol packages. On Wireshark I got a RST (SSH) followed by loads of retransmits, finally the connection was closed.

So it was a connection problem.

If you think you have this problem, try the following to verify it:

- Connect to a VPN.
- Connect to your mobile network.
- Or any other alternate connection...

I have replaced my ASDL modem and everything works like a charm!